# How to write this in json format?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code that stores the data in array. But I want the output on the json format.
Currently, I can convert input data to json but I'm not sure how to change this code that works with object. 
For example the code on lines :

```
target = (children[p] || (children[p] = []));
```

and

```
target.push({value:item});
```

Any ideas?

```
for (var i = 0, len = arry.length; i < len; ++i) {
  var item = arry[i],
      p = item.Parent,
      target = [];

    if(p == rootId) {
        target = roots;
    } 
    else {              
        target = (children[p] || (children[p] = []));           
    }

    target.push({ value: item });
```

}

Comment: Assuming that what you want is really [JSON](http://json.org/) (I'm unsure) then you should use JSON.stringify.

Comment: JSON is a formatting protocol, not a data structure... Are you asking how to serialize this as JSON?

Comment: "works with JSON" is incredibly vague.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @dystroy Where should I use that?

Comment: for example. target is array and the code on target = (children[p] || (children[p] = [])); and target.push({ value: item }); works with array but not object.

Comment: JSON can only exist in JavaScript in strings. Do you mean objects maybe? And if yes, how does your code not work with objects? What do you want to change? Do you want `target` to be an object?

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, i mean the object... sorry!!

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize an arbitrary Javascript object to a JSON string by calling `JSON.stringify()`.

That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Isn't that what we call rep whoring?

Comment: my problem is target is array and the code on target = (children[p] || (children[p] = [])); and target.push({ value: item }); works with array but not object.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: No; I hit the rep limit long ago.  This is my way of answering the question while making it clear that the question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the same code work by iterating over a JS object instead of an array, then you probably want this :

```
for (var key in obj) {
  var item = obj[key];
      p = item.Parent,
      target = [];

    if(p == rootId) {
        target = roots;
    } 
    else {              
        target = (children[p] || (children[p] = []));           
    }

    target.push({ value: item });
}
```

If you're trying to start from an array but to fill an object, then maybe you want this :

```
for (var i = 0, len = arry.length; i < len; ++i) {
  var item = arry[i],
      p = item.Parent,
      target = [];

    if(p == rootId) {
        target = roots;
    } 
    else {              
        target = (children[p] || (children[p] = {}));           
    }
    target.value = item;
}
```

I'd suggest you to read the good MDN introduction on objects and properties : [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)